# Adding padding to span element when an error message occurs in CSS

Tags: html, css, django

In my project, I have a form where users can signup. If an error occurs, I pass it through from my backend(Django) to my frontend. Here in the HTMl, I do an If statement to see if the error has been passed and if so, I want to display it below the field that caused the error.

I successfully display the error below the form field the error came from. I display the error inside a span element. The only problem is that I want to add some space above and below the span element itself.

I attempt this, but no space at all is added.

**Here is the code relating to this:**

```
<!-This is a flexbox container below->
<div class="flex-container">
 <form class="signupForm" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if usernameError %}
                    <span style="color: #E77B04; position:relative; top: 62px; font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 15px;"> {{ usernameError }} </span>
                {% endif %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field }}
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
                <button class="signupBtn" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**Browser Displayed code:**

```
 <form class="signupForm" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="#">

                    <span style="color: #E77B04; position:relative; top: 62px; font-size: 15px; padding-top: 15px;"> The username provided is not available </span>


                    <input type="text" name="username" value="edu333nir" placeholder="Username" class="usernameField" maxlength="255" minlength="4" required id="id_username">
                    <br>

                    <input type="email" name="email" value="edmundeded@edmdede.com" placeholder="Email" class="emailField" maxlength="255" minlength="2" required id="id_email">
                    <br>

                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="passwordField" minlength="6" required id="id_password">
                    <br>

                    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="confirmPassField" minlength="1" required id="id_confirmPassword">
                    <br>

                <button class="signupBtn" type="submit">Sign up</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: This code will only add padding to top of span, you need padding bottom too

Comment: @Unknown No I know that but even padding to the top is not working.

Comment: @Unknown Check the updated code. I have added padding to the bottom and pasted into my code.

Comment: Please post the generated html of this section

Comment: @Unknown Still no space is added to the top or bottom.

Comment: @Unknown The generated element is just a string. If i remove the span, it just displays a plain string.

Comment: @Unknown Python/Django doesn't generate the HTMl for the error, it just passes the string/message to it.

Comment: I mean the HTML that is displayed in the browser...thats the place to start debugging usually

Comment: @Unknown I have done it. Check my original post as I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I have moved the conditional rendering of the error message to be inside the loop that renders the fields. Now for each field a check is done to check if the error message is no blank **AND** if the field has the name 'username', if they are both true THEN add the error message beneath the field :

```
<!-This is a flexbox container below->
<div class="flex-container">
 <form class="signupForm" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field }}
                    {% if usernameError and field.name == "username" %}
                    <span style="color: #E77B04; font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 15px;"> {{ usernameError }} </span>
                {% endif %}
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
                <button class="signupBtn" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello this does not work. When I remove position relative, the text is not displayed beneath the username field. When I do margin-top, that does not work in this instance, with padding being also applied.

Comment: @eweee sorry I mean the `form` in `{% for field in form %}`

Comment: This is generated by Django forms. You can see the generated form code in the original post where I post the page source for this section.

Comment: Where are you defining the inputs that the form will have?

Comment: In Django within the file forms.py. These generate the inputs but I don't think these cause the problem.

Comment: see my comment on the other answer, you need to check inside the loop if the field is the one that you want to render the span next to and then render it there, I will update my answer

Comment: Check my comment in the other post.

Comment: Hello. When implementing this, I get the error **Could not parse the remainder: '&&' from '&&'**

Comment: try now? @eweee

Comment: When implementing this, I get the error **Could not parse the remainder: '===' from '==='**

Comment: sorry just having a moment... try now :) @eweee

Comment: It works! Thank you. Do mind explaining the code that you inserted (the if statement in the code)

Comment: added to answer :) @eweee

Comment: One thing I still don't understand is the **field.errors** part of the if statement.  What does this refer to?

Comment: not sure field.errors is, if you mean field.name it refers to the name of the field (can be seen in the generated HTML)

Comment: Ah yes that is what I meant. I am very sorry but I still don't quite understand the logic part of the if statement. Can you try explain this to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204265/discussion-between-unknown-and-eweee).

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your property:

**padding:bottom** *invalid*

**padding-bottom** *correct*

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Hello. I have applied this but still no space at all is added.

Comment: Than wrap it in <div> and apply padding to div, something like: <div style="padding: 15px 0;"><span style="font-size: 14px; ...">message</span></div>. And the position:relative is unnecessary here as well. And check your developer tools in case something is overwriting your padding settings

Comment: When doing this, the span is not positioned beneath the username input field.

Comment: Instead when applying margin-top, the whole form moves with the span. I only want this margin applied to the span element individually.

Comment: than wrap both input field and span in div, it is easier to style them. And check out for

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#server-side

if it is applicable to your project I would recommend to use bootstrap. It makes your life much easier.

Comment: I already have bootstrap and use it in different parts of my website. And I tried wrapping the input in the span at the beginning. This also did not work.

Comment: why not using bootstrap here?

Comment: @kajdzo the issue here is that they are trying to display a bunch of fields and then 'manually' adjust the span to appear underneath the correct field. The solution is to move the span to inside the for loop and have a if statement to check if the field is the one relevant to the span and then render the span (hopefully this makes sense)

Comment: @Unknown I have moved the span inside the loop, however when the if statement evaluates to true, it is added beneath every field instead of just one(which I need)

Comment: @kajdzo I don't need bootstrap here as It does not suit needs and will also not take care of the solution.

Comment: Yes, you need to identify the field is the correct one aswell: {% if usernameError && field.Name === "correctName" %} or something like that